# Why does a file within a docker volume not get overwritten?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm trying to understand volumes.

When I build and run this image with `docker build -t myserver .` and `docker run -dp 8080:80 myserver`, the web server on it prints "Hallo". When I change "Hallo" to "Huhu" in the `Dockerfile` and rebuild & run the image/container, it shows "Huhu". So far, no surprises.

Next, I added a `docker-compose.yaml` file that has two volumes. One volume is mounted on an existing path of where the `Dockerfile` creates the index.html. The other is mounted on a new and unused path. I build and run everything with `docker compose up --build`.

On the first build, the web server prints "Hallo" as expected. I can also see the two volumes in Docker GUI and its contents. The index.html that was written to the image, is now present in the volume. (I guess the volume gets mounted *before* the Dockerfile can write to it.)

On the second build (swap "Hallo" with "huhu" and run `docker compose up --build` again) I was expecting the webserver to print "Huhu". But it prints "Hallo". So I'm not sure why the data on the volume was not overwritten by the Dockerfile.

Can you explain?

Here are the files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

# First build
RUN echo "Hallo" > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

# Second build
# RUN echo "Huhu" > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - persistent:/persistent
volumes:
  html:
  persistent:
```

Comment: In the second case, the volume already exists (with the "Hello") from the first time you used `docker-compose up -d` and will be mounted again into the container, which overwrites the folder in the image (with "Huhu") with the content of the volume (with "Hello")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three different cases here:

1. When you build the image, it knows nothing about volumes.  Whatever string is in that `RUN echo` line, it is stored in the image.  Volumes are not mounted when you run the `docker-compose build` step, and the Dockerfile cannot write to a volume at all.
2. The first time you run a container with the volume mounted, and the first time only, if the volume is empty, Docker copies content from the mount point in the image into the volume.  This only happens with named volumes and not bind mounts; it only happens on native Docker and not Kubernetes; the volume content is never updated at all after this happens.
3. The second time you run a container with the volume mounted, since the volume is already populated, the content from the volume hides the content in the image.

You routinely see various cases that uses named volumes to "pass through" to the image (especially Node applications) or to "share files" with another container (frequently an Nginx server).  These only work because Docker (and only Docker) automatically populates empty named volumes, and therefore they only work the first time.  If you change your `package.json`, your Node application that mounts a volume over `node_modules` won't see updates; if you change your static assets that you're sharing with a Web server, the named volume will hide those changes in both the application and HTTP-server containers.

Since the named-volume auto-copy only happens in this one very specific case, I'd try to avoid using it, and more generally try to avoid mounting anything over non-empty directories in your image.